# How do I clear the js memory on chrome

Tags: javascript, json, memcached

I am trying to test a JS change and seems like I am not able to update the cache memory of my chorme. I tried a shorcut F5+ control on mac long time back but didnt seem to work this time round.

Any hints ?

Comment: Developer tools -> Network Tab -> Right click -> clear browser cache

Comment: `F12 > Network > tick Disable Cache` for testing.

Answer (score 1):

add some no-chache tags.

```
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Cache" content="no-cache">
```